# Javascript or html event leap

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've got a problem. i have N contenteditable="true" div's

```
    <div class="btn-group"  *ngFor="let item of cpu; let i = index;">
        <div  contenteditable="true" (keydown.enter) = "memorychange($event,i)" class="memory_cells btn btn-default">
            {{ cpu[i] }} 
        </div>
    </div>
```

And every div have onkeydown event that recieve event and index of div.

```
    memorychange(event:any, index:number) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (event.target.innerHTML as number > 255) {
            this.cpu[index] = 255;
        }
        else {
            this.cpu[index] = event.target.innerHTML as number;
        }

        event.target.innerHTML = this.cpu[index];
        event.target.blur();

        return false;
    }
```

code works fine, but there is one problem. When im click enter, array saving my value and js or html jumping to the next element and put this value to the next contenteditable div - its look like this: 
[event jumping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iSsM.jpg)

how to fix this?:(
but when i comment assigment `event.target.innerHTML = this.cpu[index];` and `this.cpu[index] = 255;` there is no jump :\

Comment: Why do you use contenteditable? It is known for bugs and unexpected behavior

Comment: same problem with inputs

Comment: You should consider editing your post for clarity of expression; as it stands, what you are trying to achieve isn't clear just as the error you are getting.